# How to preserve checkbox checked status in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I am developing MVC4 application and I have paging. I have one checkbox in the page. I am using paging so i want to preserve the values of all fields. I am using Models and viewbag to preserve the values for textbox and dropdownlist. I am finding difficuties with checkbox to preserve the value.

For example, dropdownbox is as follows,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.doc_typeid, Model.doctype_name, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

For example, Textbox is as follows,

```
       @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.employeeID, Model.employeeID, new { @id = "employeeID", @placeholder = "Employee ID", @class = "form-control text-input", @maxlength = 20 })
```

This is my checkbox.

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmploymentType.Count; i++)
 {
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].isChecked, new { id = "employmentType_" + i })
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].checkBoxName)
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EmploymentType[i].checkBoxName)
 }
```

Here I am not sure how to preserve the checkbox checked value? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes by themselves will not preserve when a request is made back to the server.  The main way to preserve it is always make sure the checkboxes are in a form that postback to the server.  When the form posts back, grab them from the `Model.EmploymentType` collection.

You just have to be careful that everything that performs an action is actually a POST, not GET.

Answer (score 0):

that's what the model is for.

Imagine you have a view with a form, a dropdown and a button to submit the form. 
When you hit the button you get a model object back to your controller. Now you want to redisplay the form so at this point you need to pass the existing model as it is back to the view.

So, before the postback your Action could do this:

```
Return View("someView");
```

After postback you want to change that to

```
Return View("someView", model);
```

The model is what you got back to the controller after the first submit.

Does that make sense?

Don't try to rely too much on ViewBag or Session or something else. The model can cover all this for you nicely.